# set the selected value of DropDownList in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an editable Gridview.  I would like when I put the gridview in edit mode the selected value of the gridview is set.

the template field in the gridview.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <%#Eval("Status")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddStatusList" AppendDataBoundItems="True" CssClass="form-control">

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

the rowdatabound event

```
protected void grdPresenters_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddStatusList");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
                row1["Status"] = "Pending";
                dt.Rows.Add(row1);
                DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
                row2["Status"] = "Approved";
                dt.Rows.Add(row2);
                DataRow row3 = dt.NewRow();
                row3["Status"] = "Rejected";
                dt.Rows.Add(row3);
                ddList.DataSource = dt;
                ddList.DataTextField = "Status";
                ddList.DataValueField = "Status";
                ddList.DataBind();

                DataRowView rowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
                    String status = rowView["Status"].ToString();
                    ddList.SelectedValue = rowView["Status"].ToString();
               
            }
        }
    }
```

unfortunately rowView is always null even though in non edit mode I can see the status as approved.

Comment: The code looks correct. As @Greg says it is probably the `rowView`. What happens if you leave out that part and set the `ddList.SelectedValue` to a fixed test string. And if you are binding a `List<T>` to the GridView, the cast of the row should be something like this: `var rowView = e.Row.DataItem as MyCustomClass;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting the value of Status into a HiddenField in your edit template, and then use e.Row.FindControl to get the HiddenField value.